# Udev rules do not work on fedora 24

Tags: bash, usb, fedora, udev, fedora-25

I am trying to execute a script when a usb is plug in on fedora 24 automatically. I've found a lot of information about how to do this one on old versions. However, in Fedora 25 it does not work. This is what i do:

I have created a file in /etc/udev/rules.d/ named 60-francisco.rules and with next content but it does not work:

KERNEL=="sdb1",SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="DataTraveler_G3", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0951", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1643", RUN+="/root/usb_script.sh"

(Everything is in a line...)

This is the result of udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=/dev/sdb command

```
Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb':
    KERNEL=="sdb"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{alignment_offset}=="0"
    ATTR{badblocks}==""
    ATTR{capability}=="51"
    ATTR{discard_alignment}=="0"
    ATTR{events}=="media_change"
    ATTR{events_async}==""
    ATTR{events_poll_msecs}=="-1"
    ATTR{ext_range}=="256"
    ATTR{inflight}=="       0        0"
    ATTR{range}=="16"
    ATTR{removable}=="1"
    ATTR{ro}=="0"
    ATTR{size}=="15215808"
    ATTR{stat}=="    1199     8515    16953     1913        0        0        0        0        0     1440     1913"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="4:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"
    ATTRS{device_blocked}=="0"
    ATTRS{device_busy}=="0"
    ATTRS{dh_state}=="detached"
    ATTRS{eh_timeout}=="10"
    ATTRS{evt_capacity_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_inquiry_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_lun_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_media_change}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_mode_parameter_change_reported}=="0"
    ATTRS{evt_soft_threshold_reached}=="0"
    ATTRS{inquiry}==""
    ATTRS{iocounterbits}=="32"
    ATTRS{iodone_cnt}=="0x5a8"
    ATTRS{ioerr_cnt}=="0x2"
    ATTRS{iorequest_cnt}=="0x5a8"
    ATTRS{max_sectors}=="240"
    ATTRS{model}=="DataTraveler G3 "
    ATTRS{queue_depth}=="1"
    ATTRS{queue_type}=="none"
    ATTRS{rev}=="PMAP"
    ATTRS{scsi_level}=="0"
    ATTRS{state}=="running"
    ATTRS{timeout}=="30"
    ATTRS{type}=="0"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="Kingston"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/host4/target4:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target4:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0/host4':
    KERNELS=="host4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6/3-6:1.0':
    KERNELS=="3-6:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="08"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="50"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="06"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-6':
    KERNELS=="3-6"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="200mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="44"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="6"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="1643"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0951"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Kingston"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="DataTraveler G3"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
    ATTRS{serial}=="001CC0EC31EDBB40271A01BA"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="4137"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3':
    KERNELS=="usb3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0408"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.8.16-200.fc24.x86_64 xhci-hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="10"
    ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1453"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x8c31"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="26"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-1"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8534"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Like you can see the information in the file is good so i do not know why it does not work. I have tried every combination but there is no way..

Please, anybody can help me?

Regards,

Comment: First decipher whether the script is being executed or not. Create a script that touches a file and check the date stamp to ensure that the script is firing.

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute `ATTRS{product}=="DataTraveler G3"` for `ENV{ID_MODEL}=="DataTraveler_G3"`, you won't be dependent on other rules to be triggered which set the `ID_MODEL` variable before your rule is applied. Since the rules files are sorted lexically, the problem might also be solved by renaming your rules file so that it sorts later. From your `udevadm` output, it's likely that the `ID_MODEL` variable is missing.